# Substitute std::ofstream's underlying rdbuf with std::stringstream's underlying rdbuf

Tags: c++, io, stringstream, ofstream

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    auto ofs = std::ofstream{"out.txt"};
    if (!ofs) { throw std::runtime_error{"ofstream"}; }
    
    auto ss = std::stringstream{};
    ss << "Hello world\n";

    static_cast<std::ostream&>(ofs).rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
}
```

What I'm think is going to happen by the end of a program is `ofs` being RAII-closed and `ss`'s buffer contents are to be written to `out.txt`. But `out.txt` is empty. What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Why the cast? Due to inheritance, `ofs` *is a* `std::ostream` already.

Comment: *"What am I getting wrong ?"*  It is the filebuf that does the actual writing, not the fstream.

Comment: Specifically your code does not call [this method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/close) which is where the writing happens and the file is closed.

Comment: @john the buffer does still get closed and destroyed when `ofs` is destroyed, `rdbuf` doesn't change ownership of the buffers

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes the buffer is closed, but because it is the wrong buffer the file does not get closed.

Comment: @john, no the file does get closed, the string stream buffer is destroyed when `ss` is destroyed, the file buf is destroyed when `ofs` is destroyed which [closes the file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/%7Ebasic_filebuf)

Comment: e.g. see https://godbolt.org/z/757zxM5dM (note that this is actually undefined behaviour as `filebuf` is no longer valid after `ofs.reset()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ofstream`'s default buffer is [`std::filebuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf), which is what manages writing to the file. By [replacing that buffer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) with a [`std::stringbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf), you are effectively turning your file stream into a string stream, where any writes to the `std::ofstream` will then go to a `std::string` in memory rather than to the file.

If what you actually want to do is write the contents of the `std::stringstream`'s buffer into the file, you can do this instead:

```
ofs << ss.rdbuf();
```